# Posting complex objects with form?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi

I have following in REACT:

```
let form = new FormData();
form.append("test",test);

for (var index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
  var element = files[index];
  form.append('file', element);
}

axios.post('https://localhost:44371/api/default', form,'sdfdsf')
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch((ex) => {
            console.error(ex);
        });
```

And this in asp.net core web api:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post(IFormCollection form,string test2)
{
    var test = form["test"];

    foreach (var file in form.Files)
    {
        UploadFile(file);
    }
}
```

And it works as expected. I can add keys as strings in the form and extract those in the API. But is there anyway to pass a complex type with the form? Optimal would be if I attach an object as a parameter on the API function. Or it it a constrain that when posting a form that is the only you can post?

Comment: A normal form post is based on `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so it is just a list of key-value pair. While it is possible to have some level of hierarchy that way with the standard ASP.NET Core model binder, you should post a serialized body, e.g. using JSON instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there anyway to pass a complex type with the form? Optimal would be if I attach an object as a parameter on the API function.

To achieve above requirement, you can refer to the following sample code snippet.

On client side

```
let form = new FormData();
form.append("test", "testc");

for (var index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
    var element = files[index];
    form.append('file', element);
}

form.append("childP.name", "blablahere");

axios.post('https://xxxxx/api/default', form, 'sdfdsf')
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch((ex) => {
        console.error(ex);
    });
```

API controller action

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromForm]TestModel testModel)
{

    var test = testModel.test;

    foreach (var file in testModel.file)
    {
        UploadFile(file);
    }

    var childp_name = testModel.childP.name;

    //code logic here
    //...
}
```

Model class

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string test { get; set; }
    public List<IFormFile> file { get; set; }
    public ChildP childP { get; set; }
}

public class ChildP
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Test Result

[image]